# htaccess 301 redirect after changing file name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I use this rewrite:

```
RewriteRule post-(.*)\.html$ post.php?id=$1
```

but have since changed the file name post.php to photo.php so i changed it to

```
RewriteRule photo-(.*)\.html$ photo.php?id=$1
```

which is fine but I have been getting errors in my logs when visitors come from search engines and get directed to original file name post.php?id=? so need to add (I think) a 301 redirect, I have tried:

```
RewriteRule photo-(.*)\.html$ post.php?id=$1
```

and:

```
RewriteRule photo-(.*)\.html$ post-(.*)\.html$[L,R=301]
```

but neither work and to be honest haven't really got a clue, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want it to be the other way around. When people go to your *old* URL (`post.php?id=`), redirect to the *new* one. You either want one of these:

```
RewriteRule post-(.*)\.html$ photo-$1.html [R=301]

RewriteRule post\.php$ photo.php [R=301]
```

The first takes a URL like http://hostname.com/post-1234.html and redirects the browser to http://hostname.com/photo-1234.html so your rules can rewrite it to photo.php, the second does the same except http://hostname.com/post.php?id=1234 to http://hostname.com/photo.php?id=1234 (note that the query string automatically gets appended to the end in the second rule).

Comment: Thank you marked as answer - "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" so can't vote it right now sorry.